# Integration as a limit of a sum.

Tags: calculus, integration

If [.] denotes the greatest integer function and {x}=x-[x], then the value of $\int_0^1x\{\frac 1x\}[\frac 1x] $dx is equal to, if $ \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac 1k^{2} $ = $ \frac {\pi^{2}}6 $

(1) $\frac {\pi^{2}}{12} $ $\quad$  (2) $ \frac {\pi^{2}}{12} - \frac 12 $

(3) $\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\{x\}[x]}{x^{3}} dx $ $\quad $  (4) $\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\{x\}[x]}{x^{2}}dx $

I have been struggling with this problem for quite a long now. First step I did was to substitute x= $\frac 1t $ in the given expression which easily turns out to be the one given in option 3.  What I am really struggling with is how to convert this integral into a limit of sum. From what I have read about integrals as a limit of limit of sum is that we can write $ \lim_{n \to \infty }\frac 1n \sum_{r=1}^{\infty}f(\frac rn) = \int_0^1f(x) dx $ $\quad $ and vice versa. But I cannot understand how to turn the expression in the question to this form. I am trying to convert to this form as a limit is given in the question which seems to be the hint that we have to solve this particular integral by this method. This is a multiple choice question by the way. More than one options can be correct.

Comment: Try computing $$\int_{\frac{1}{n+1}}^{\frac1n}$$ of your integrand. Then sum from $n=1$ to $\infty.$

Comment: Can you explain why did you think of such a step. How should I do this.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math SE. To understand @ThomasAndrews's motivation, try sketching a plot of $x\{\frac1x\}[\frac1x]$.

Comment: Even without a plot, it is uttermost natural to partition the interval of integration into subintervals where the integer $[\frac 1x]$ is constant.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, let’s express the integrand in terms of [.].
$$
\begin{aligned}\int_0^1 x\left\{\frac{1}{x}\right\}\left[\frac{1}{x}\right] d x = & \int_0^1 x\left(\frac{1}{x}-\left[\frac{1}{x}\right]\right)\left[\frac{1}{x}\right] d x \\
= & \int_0^1\left(\left[\frac{1}{x}\right]-x\left[\frac{1}{x}\right]^2 \right) d x
\end{aligned}
$$
Then splitting the integral $(0,1)$ into infinite number of subintervals as
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^1 x\left\{\frac{1}{x}\right\}\left[\frac{1}{x}\right] d x  &=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_{\frac{1}{n+1}}^{\frac{1}{n}}\left(\left[\frac{1}{x}\right]-x\left[\frac{1}{x}\right]^2\right) d x \\
& =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_{\frac{1}{n+1}}^{\frac{1}{n}}\left(n-n^2 x\right) d x\\&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[n x-\frac{n^2 x^2}{2}\right]_{\frac{1}{n}}^{\frac{1}{n}}
\end{aligned}
$$
Simplifying yields
$$\int_0^1 x\left\{\frac{1}{x}\right\}\left[\frac{1}{x}\right] d x =\frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}= \frac{\pi^2}{12}-\frac{1}{2} $$

Wish it helps.

Comment: Thanks Lai. I was struggling with this for many days.

Comment: I am glad to know that it helps.